# How to bind a button in one frame so that when it is clicked, it passes the control to another frame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, wxpython

I am new to wxpython and stackoverflow, so bear with me if I did any stupid mistake.

**Frame1:**

```
import wx

def create(parent):
    return Frame1(parent)

[wxID_FRAME1, wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1, wxID_FRAME1PANEL1, wxID_FRAME1SLIDER1, 
 wxID_FRAME1STATICTEXT1, 
] = [wx.NewId() for _init_ctrls in range(5)]



class Frame1(wx.Frame):
    def _init_ctrls(self, prnt):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, id=wxID_FRAME1, name='', parent=prnt,
              pos=wx.Point(710, 314), size=wx.Size(483, 276),
              style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, title='Frame1')
        self.SetClientSize(wx.Size(467, 237))

        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(id=wxID_FRAME1PANEL1, name='panel1', parent=self,
              pos=wx.Point(0, 0), size=wx.Size(467, 237),
              style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.button1 = wx.Button(id=wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1, label=u'ClickMe',
              name='button1', parent=self.panel1, pos=wx.Point(312, 112),
              size=wx.Size(136, 72), style=0)
        self.button1.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(64, 0, 64))
        self.button1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(128, 255, 255))
        self.button1.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_COLOUR)
        self.button1.SetFont(wx.Font(12, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False,
              u'Gill Sans Ultra Bold'))
        self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton1Button,
              id=wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1)

        self.staticText1 = wx.StaticText(id=wxID_FRAME1STATICTEXT1,
              label=u'HelloWorld', name='staticText1', parent=self.panel1,
              pos=wx.Point(168, 16), size=wx.Size(130, 29), style=0)
        self.staticText1.SetFont(wx.Font(20, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL,
              False, u'Ubuntu Mono'))

        self.slider1 = wx.Slider(id=wxID_FRAME1SLIDER1, maxValue=100,
              minValue=0, name='slider1', parent=self.panel1, pos=wx.Point(64,
              144), size=wx.Size(100, 24), style=wx.SL_HORIZONTAL, value=0)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._init_ctrls(parent)

    def OnButton1Button(self, event):
        event.Skip()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = create(None)
    frame.Show()

    app.MainLoop()
```

**Frame2:**

```
import wx

def create(parent):
    return Frame1(parent)

[wxID_FRAME1, wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1, wxID_FRAME1PANEL1, wxID_FRAME1SLIDER1, 
 wxID_FRAME1STATICTEXT1, 
] = [wx.NewId() for _init_ctrls in range(5)]



class Frame1(wx.Frame):
    def _init_ctrls(self, prnt):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, id=wxID_FRAME1, name='', parent=prnt,
              pos=wx.Point(710, 314), size=wx.Size(483, 276),
              style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, title='Frame1')
        self.SetClientSize(wx.Size(467, 237))

        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(id=wxID_FRAME1PANEL1, name='panel1', parent=self,
              pos=wx.Point(0, 0), size=wx.Size(467, 237),
              style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.button1 = wx.Button(id=wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1, label=u'ClickMe',
              name='button1', parent=self.panel1, pos=wx.Point(312, 112),
              size=wx.Size(136, 72), style=0)
        self.button1.SetForegroundColour(wx.Colour(64, 0, 64))
        self.button1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(128, 255, 255))
        self.button1.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_COLOUR)
        self.button1.SetFont(wx.Font(12, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False,
              u'Gill Sans Ultra Bold'))
        self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton1Button,
              id=wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1)

        self.staticText1 = wx.StaticText(id=wxID_FRAME1STATICTEXT1,
              label=u'HelloWorld', name='staticText1', parent=self.panel1,
              pos=wx.Point(168, 16), size=wx.Size(130, 29), style=0)
        self.staticText1.SetFont(wx.Font(20, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL,
              False, u'Ubuntu Mono'))

        self.slider1 = wx.Slider(id=wxID_FRAME1SLIDER1, maxValue=100,
              minValue=0, name='slider1', parent=self.panel1, pos=wx.Point(64,
              144), size=wx.Size(100, 24), style=wx.SL_HORIZONTAL, value=0)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self._init_ctrls(parent)

    def OnButton1Button(self, event):
        event.Skip()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = create(None)
    frame.Show()

    app.MainLoop()
```

I want to link these frames so that when I click the button in frame1 , frame2 opens. I want to bind the button with proper method to pass the control to another frame.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have at least two different frame classes. Then you can make this happen. There is no way to create a second frame based on the frame that you're already in. You could create a frame class and have two other classes sub-class the first one so they both look the same.

Regardless, if you want to show a second frame when you press your button, then you'll need to some code to the button handler. Something like this should work:

```
secondFrame = Frame2()
secondFrame.Show()
```

If you want to hide the first frame when you open the second frame and show the first frame when you close the second frame, then you'll probably need to use something like pubsub, which comes with wxPython. I wrote an article about this very process here:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/